# JQGrid on scroll pagination not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, pagination

I have used JQGrid in the application.I want to do pagination programatically so I reload grid with the next page in gridComplete method.However when I load next page my previous page data will be removed from the grid and only new data is present in the grid.Can someone please help me with this scenario.

Here is my code

```
$("#mygrid").jqGrid({
        datatype:'local',
        width: "100%",
        height: "205",
        colNames:colNames,
        colModel:colModel,
        mtype:'POST',
        rowNum: 20,
        scroll : true,
        gridview : true,
        loadtext: 'building list...',
        jsonReader: {
            repeatitems: false,
        },
        rownumbers: true,
        gridComplete: function(){
            if (jQuery("#mygrid").getGridParam('datatype') === "json") {
                var Rows = jQuery("#mygrid").getDataIDs();
                var found = false;
                for(a=0; a<Rows.length; a++) {
                        var rowid = Rows[a];
                        var rowData = $("#mygrid").getRowData(rowid);
                        if(rowData['test'] == 'test'){
                            $("#mygrid").setSelection(rowid, true);
                            found = true;
                            break;
                        }

                    if(!found) {
                        var curPage = jQuery("#mygrid").getGridParam('page');
                        setTimeout(function(){  
                            var total = jQuery("#mygrid").getGridParam('lastpage');
                            if(total != curPage){
                                jQuery("#mygrid").setGridParam(
                                        { page: curPage + 1 }).trigger("reloadGrid");
                            }
                         },100);  
                    }
                }
            }
        }
});
 $("#mygrid").jqGrid().setGridParam({
        url : url, 
        mtype: 'POST',
        page : 1, 
        datatype : "json",
        ajaxGridOptions: { 
            type :"POST",
            contentType :"application/json; charset=utf-8"
        },
        serializeGridData: function(postData) {
            postData['criteria'] =  criteria;
            postData['pageSize'] =  20;
            return JSON.stringify(postData);
        }
    });
```

I am using  Guriddo jqGrid JS - v5.0.1

Here let's say i didn't find the 'test' next page will get load however, when i scroll up the grid reloads previous pages and it removes the selection

Comment: You should include JavaScript code, which you use. You should include more information about the data which you need to display, for example the total number of rows (100, 1000, 10000, ...). You should include in every question about jqGrid the version number of jqGrid and write which fork of jqGrid you use or can use ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7).

Comment: @Oleg just added the code please help.

Comment: I repeat my question about **the total number of rows, which you need to display**. Moreover I don't recommend to use `scroll : true` (virtual scrolling). The code from `gridComplete` and usage `datatype: "local"` first and immediately changing it to `"json"` looks very strange. It seems that you need just use `loadonce: true` scenario, but it's depend from the total number or rows. Moreover I develop free jqGrid fork and implemented creating *selected* rows and *local* sorting and filtering the data initially loaded from the server, before it will be first displayed. Is it what you want?

Comment: the total number of rows would not be fixed rows these are dynamic and I just want to iterate through the pages till I get the value to be selected. And I am able to achieve that however when I scroll up the previous pages will get load(Again building the list making calls to backend).This grid has no sorting or any other feature except the virtual scrolling.

Comment: @Oleg please help me with this.

Comment: Let use you construct the auto, which drives over the city with 50 km/h or you construct the auto, which will drive 2000 km with 250 km/h every day. You will use absolutely different materials for the auto. In the same way you should implement the grid in different way for total 500 rows or 500000 rows. Thus you have to answer on the question about *approximately* number of rows, which you need to display totally.

Comment: @Oleg this grid will have maximum 1000 rows

Comment: Iteration the data on the client size and reloading the pages one after another one is **very ineffective**. Instead of that you should do this on the backend (in the database for example) and just return directly the page with the requested information.

Comment: Look on [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/performane-13-4000-20-free-jqgrid.htm) with 4000 rows and 13 columns and the page size 20 rows. You can see the performance of *local* paging, sorting and filtering. I'd recommend you to use `loadonce: true` scenario for 1000 rows. I think that the round trip of HTTP request to the server takes more time as local paging.

Comment: can't we do anything with what I implemented already? I mean the onscroll pagination beacuse that feature is a must and thanks for your inputs.

Comment: You are welcome, but I think the way which you describes absolutely wrong. It's slow, the code is long (on the server side and on the client). You can change the code just to return **all the data** at once and displays the filter directly on load if it's require (all this can do free jqGrid and can't Guriddo), or just sort the data so that the line with `'test'` will be the first and to select the first row. There are many options, but all not in the way like in your original code.